# Mysterious Murder

Tags: mystery

A man and his wife are on vacation. They take a ship to and from an island resort. After the vacation, the man is reported by their travel agent and arrested for the murder of his wife. How did the travel agent know the man was the murderer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because,

> the man only booked one ticket for the return trip

Comment: Not to quibble but doesnt everyone book a round trip when they go on vacation?